# Как организовать хранение данных в Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

**Всем привет!**

Интересует вопрос по создания многопользовательского приложения на AngularJS совместно с Firebase. Имею представление о том, как с ней работать, как сделать регистрацию и авторизацию, но не знаю, как лучше организовать структуру хранения данных. 
Приложение - простенький todolist с набором списков задач. Нужно, чтобы у каждого пользователя был свой набор списков и задач соответственно. 
Как лучше все это оформить, чтобы получение нужных данных не было слишком трудозатратным? 
Под каждого пользователя при регистрации создавать свой объект, в котором и хранить массив его списков или может как-то иначе?
Был бы рад услышать мнение тех, кто уже сталкивался с подобной задачей или получить пару ссылок на статьи, если у кого-то вдруг завалялись=)

Comment: https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/

Answer (score 1):

На счет регистрации и логинации я уже писал, вот - [Получить имя пользователя из Firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503538/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-firebase) .
На счет наполнения. Я думаю удобнее всего будет использовать схему FireBase/Todos/Uid/. При создании такой схемы будет удобно получать данные. Как их получить в том же вопросе, ответ.