# Получить имя пользователя из Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Проблема такая. Пишу чат используя хранилище данных FireBase. 
Использую стандартную регистрацию через email + password. Во время регистрации 
запрашиваю так же желаемое имя пользователя. В базу записываю  username и email.
По uid, который генерируется автоматически, но дело в том, что для каждой новой записи, firebase создает свой ключ, который я получить из клиентской части не могу, при логинации. Из всего этого я знаю только **uid** и email. Это возвращает сервер при логинации. Вопрос: как при схеме Firebase/users/%random%/uid/username, email получить **username**? Либо подскажите как делать запись игнорируя %random key%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился, изменил принцип записи в Firebase. Теперь запись пользователя и email происходит так:

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users/" + userData.uid); 
usersRef.push( { Username: username, email: email, }
```

С получением данных тоже были вопросы. Но уже решил. Чтобы получить данные нужно:

1. Добавить ссылку на папку с UID `var usersRef = ref.child("users/" + authData.uid);`
2. Потом нужно получить снепшот, далее его прогнать через $.map два раза, а потом можно обращаться к элементам через индекс массива.

Мой код:

```
var users = new Firebase("https://<yourappname>.firebaseio.com/users");    
var authData = users.getAuth();
var usersRef = ref.child("users/" + authData.uid);
usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val();
var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el });
var arr = $.map(arr[0], function(el) { return el });
console.log("this is a username ->" + arr[0] + " & this is a email->" + arr[1]);});
```